# Вывод большой таблицы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется html таблица на >500 строк, вывод ее генерируется php. В браузере все это добро порядком тормозит. Можно ли оптимизировать рендер, но только желательно не многостраничным методом, так как имеется множество таблиц, которые на друг друга ссылаются и ссылки ведут на конкретную запись в таблице, на которую срабатывает автоскролл (`JQuery.scrollTo()`). Не хочу себе усложнять жизнь)). Хотя если решения нет, приму вариант с каким-нибудь плагином, который реализует многостраничность.

Comment: Тормозит html таблица?О_о<br>
Жажду пруфлинк... Ксатит - ПРИЧЕМ ТУТ РЕНДЕР? >_<

Comment: Сорри неправильно выразился, под рендером я имею виду принцип вывода. Возможно есть смысл скрыть часть таблицы как-нибудь в DOM, а при скролле выхватывать ту часть, которая попадает в область видимости, но у меня подозрения, что движок это и так делает. Тормозит очень сильно огнелис, чуть меньше хром - все под линуксом.

Comment: ИМХО - не в ту сторону копаете...

Comment: А плагина-обертки нету, чтобы асинхронно подгружалось в скажем div, а jquery разбивал бы весь контент автоматически на страницы?

Comment: Вы бы лучше поискал плагин который будет за Вас весь код писать :)<br>
Обьем не является проблемой ( хотите доказать обратное? жду пруфлинка )<br>
Не люблю повторятся, но - не в ту сторону копаете...

Comment: Было бы неплохо:) Это не сайт, а система инвентаризации, скинул бы да все на работе. А суть проста - пятьсот строк в таблице плюс подсветка строк с помощью псевдокласса hover. Я бы написал бы код здесь - только туплю не могу вставить так, чтобы html теги не парсились.

Comment: Вопрос о производительности снимаю, протестировал таблицу с 4000 строк, с активной подсветкой и автоскроллом - очень приемлемо, но это windows 7, а тормоза были в OpenSUSE(браузер Огнелис 7, Chrome), причем машина была напорядок сильнее.

Comment: Лично я даже не слышал о таком браузере, надо было с это и начинать - тестил в "африканском" браузере, медленно работает :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope 

OpenSUSE - ось, Огнелис - Firefox )

Comment: @user3545, подскажите, а в какую сторону копать нужно?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это всеж зависит от компьютера клиента. Насколько он "быстр". А Вывод делайте как хотите. Прятать тоже не вариант, ибо будет тот же результат и даже хуже. НО если подгружать таблицу и пихать подгруженные строки `$.append()`-ом, думаю более менее облегчит задачу.

Answer (score 1):

1. Программным путем разделите хтмл контент по количеству слов (к примеру, 1000 слов на страницу).
2. Выводите этот кусок на экран.
3. Сделайте скрипт на жквери который после `$(window).load` начнет подгружать остальные куски один за другим.
4. А на ссылки, которые будут делать скролинг поставьте нечто типа `$('a#scroll').live('click', function(){});`, т.к. будет подгружаться в дом обьект после полной загрузки. Потому надо им хендлеры поставить, которые перехватывают клик на обьект, который подгрузился в дом динамически.

Есть еще вариант. Но я не пробовал.
Плугин для жквери `lazyload`.

Comment: Предпоследний комментарий ТСа гляньте и Вы поймете, что не то :)

Comment: Я не пойму, конкретно о чем автор беспокоится. Просто предложил вариант обхода ))) Дальше уж его дело.

Comment: AlexWindHope я использовал еще Chrome, производительность последнего процентов на 30% выше, но скролл все равно тормозил. А выбор браузера остается за клиентом, а не за мной, поэтому я считаю глупым просить клиента сменить браузер, если моя система тормозит! И производительность, это не единственный ньюанс, еще важно и удобство.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема рендера таблицы в том - что браузер должен обработать все строки, дабы узнать сколько-же столбцов в таблице.
Используйте теги [< col >](http://htmlbook.ru/html/col) и [< colgroup >](http://htmlbook.ru/html/colgroup) - это даст визуальное ускорение отображения.
При большом кол-ве строк ( вес в памяти строки таблицы - достаточно велик ), можно действовать иначе: сделать таблицу на ( к примеру ) 50 строк, и реализовать JS scrollbar, который будет изменять содержимое строк при прокрутке.

Comment: Спасибо, вот это уже интересно!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел исчерпывающее решение проблемы:
[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net)